# change default identity column name in inherited (joined ) class in symfony

Tags: symfony, inheritance, key, default, identity

I have used a Class Table Inheritance so that my entity "image" inherits from the "media" Entity. 
this procedure create an auto generated column id in the image table. How can i change this default name "id" to set it "media_id" so that the image column has a column "media_id" instead of  "id" ? 
here is my code :

```
namespace App\Entity\OldApp;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \App\Entity\OldApp\TemplateContent;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OldApp\MediaRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"media" = "Media", "image" = "Image"})
 */

class Media
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="CAT_id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $filename;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="high", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $high = '0';


namespace App\Entity\OldApp;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OldApp\ImageRepository")
*/
class Image extends Media
{



/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
*/
private $extension;


private static $type='image' ;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
*/
private $ratio;


/**
* @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
*/
private $height;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
*/
private $width;
}
```

i've tryed to add `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="person_id")` Bellow @ORM\Entity but i ged the following error

**Error**

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\PrimaryKeyJoinColumn" in class App\Entity\OldApp\Image doe
>     s not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
trait MediaTrait
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $filename;
 // getter //setter
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OldApp\MediaRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"media" = "Media", "image" = "Image"})
 */

class Media
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="CAT_id")
     */
    private $id;

    use MediaTrait;
}

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OldApp\ImageRepository")
*/
class Image
{
/**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="media_id")
     */
    private $id;

    use MediaTrait;

    // reste of the code 
     ....

}
```

Comment: No this isn't working doctrine ignore this instruction cause the identifier is auto generated by it

Comment: Yes your are right!! we can not override the id. I think you can create a generic class BaseMedia without id then inherit it to Media and Image. I modify the my Answer if you wanna try.

Comment: you mean create a new entity ? it should appear as another table in base isn't it  ? i woudlike to avoid this as possible

Comment: no not an Entity just a std class, it should not have the @ORM/Entity() anotation but all the other properties will have the @ORM\Column anotation. Or maybe a trait BaseMeda its your confortable.

Comment: I have modified the answer (take advantage of trait)